# How to make Google Maps in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, maps, google

I'd like to find out how I can create a map similar to these:

[image]
[image]
[image]

especially for web design project (in psd file). Do you know how to get that kind of maps? I suppose it can be something like http://snazzymaps.com/ but I'm not sure. Hope you could help me a bit.

Comment: Hi testerix, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn;t work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. If you have any questions, please see the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or ping one of us in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Customarily, maps are created in a vector application such as Illustrator or a dedicated mapping app like Cartographer. Photoshop is just the wrong tool to generate maps of that complexity.

Comment: Hmmm, ok I see. Well, so the only solution is taking a screenshot of exists maps from snazzymaps. Anyway thank you guys.